# Unique Query By Date with highest ID taking precidence

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the newest unique dates, returning the date and the item.  I have made a example here, but its not giving me unique dates only.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(date), meal, dinner_id FROM dinner_tb ORDER BY `dinner_tb`.`date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

See there are three items on the 16th, where I should only have the Pie on that day.  Any suggestions please.  MYSQL v8.  dinner_id is primary key.

[image]

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. It distincts the whole row content, not single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MYSQL v8.

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `date` ORDER BY dinner_id DESC) rn
              FROM dinner_tb )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```